# Extract a raw name of a remote file

Tags: php, regex, header

What is the best way to extract a name (such as **file.zip**) from a URL such as:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/RANDOM-f4ymjbj/**file.zip**?token_hash=RANDOMXJmIZrfVJdxOxVJuqcln3gd0Y8g

I am not good in this stuff, but I need to know the best way. Is the file name contained somewhere in the headers? Or do I need to use a regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pathinfo(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), PATHINFO_FILENAME)`?

[pathinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)
[parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

upd: yes, I've forgotten about PHP_URL_PATH